# Как установить python 3.5 на NetBeans 8.1, если происходит "invalid python type" ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netbeans

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit

NetBeans IDE 8.1

Python 3.5.3

**Что мне нужно.** Я написал код на python 3 в netbeans. До этого использовал python 3.6. Но там нет поддержки [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#windows).

**Что я делал.** Снес и установил 3.5 и под него pycurl. При подсоединении питона NetBeans выкидывает ошибку "invalid python type". На всякий случай устанавливал 32 битный питон. Так же самая ошибка. Качаю все с официальных сайтов.

Подсоединяю python через tools > python platforms > new > путь к 3.5 exe-шнику. Plugin для питона установил. (питон 3.6 до этого работал)

**Вопрос.** Почему не подсоединяется питон и что означает ошибка? как мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: как вы подсоединяете python?

Comment: добавил обновление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблемы тем что снес питон и установил его локально на одного Юзера. Netbeans принял. В чем проблема так и не разобрался. Питон 3.5 установил тот же что и до этого.